# Deploy a React app to Netlify + AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, netlify

So I have this normal React app that is deployed in Netlify.
Then I tried using AWS Amplify for my authentication. All went well in my local.

The problem is, I think I would not be able to deploy it properly to Netlify anymore because of the aws-exports.js that is dynamically generated. Or can I? Is it still possible to deploy a React + Amplify app to Netlify? Or I have no choice but to deploy it to AWS?

UPDATE: I was able to deploy it successfully on Netlify by commenting out the aws-exports.js in the .gitignore. The problem now is how could I have different version of the file for different environments (e.g. Dev, Stage, Prod).

Comment: You’re not alone! I, too, have just recently run into a similar issue, even within the AWS ecosystem. We’re working on improving communications re: how to handle the AWS-exports file/dependencies in context of CI/CD. Will bookmark this question and respond with an answer when I have it! In the meantime, if you want to cut an issue against our docs repo, we could keep up the conversation there! https://github.com/aws-amplify/docs

Comment: @MichaelEdelman do you guys have an update on this yet? I see people mentioning that `amplifyPush --simple` combined with a service role would do the job without comitting `aws-exports.js`, but I don't understand how I would run that with Netlify.

Comment: any updates @MichaelEdelman

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `prebuild` script to your `package.json`.

```json
"scripts": {
  "prebuild": "node generateExportsFile.js"
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  ...
}
```

then you can create that `node.js` file that will generate the exports file according to your environment, or env vars, or whatever you decide.